# Links not working in chrome-extension after I've moved them to a different position

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

My google-chrome-extension moves certain div to a different place after page loaded:

```
var div = $('div.joinContributors').first();
if (div != null) {
    div.insertAfter($('div.filmRateBox').first());
}
```

and links that are stored inside that div aren't working anymore. When I inspect html code using Chrome developer tools I can see:

```
<li><a class="link" href="link_to_another_subpage" rel="nofollow">name_of_the_link</a></li>
```

But when I create new link and add it there everything works just fine:

```
$("<a>", {"href": "link_to_another_subpage", "text": "name_of_the_link"}).insertAfter($('div.filmRateBox').first());
```

Any ideas why aren't they working?

Comment: The site probably has custom event handlers for click  event on those links that checks the parent node. Try to insert as html to remove them e.g. via .html() or .prop('outerHTML')

Comment: Everything is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since the contents has normal links with proper URLs that must be handled correctly by default, the most likely reason is that the site uses custom click event handlers with parent node checks inside.

A simple solution is to insert as HTML to recreate the exact layout but strip all event handlers:

```
var $div = $('div.joinContributors').first();
if ($div.length) {
    $('div.filmRateBox').first().after($div.prop('outerHTML'));
    $div.remove();
}
```

Note that `document.querySelector` is much faster than `$('...').first()` because it doesn't build the entire collection.

Another solution, quite shaky, would be to remove the event handlers, but it'll work only for jQuery events accessible via `jQuery._data(element, 'events')` or `.onxxxxx` DOM properties.